# Creating a C++ extension for Python

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, visual-studio-2017

When I follow the instructions from [Creating a C++ extension for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/cpp-and-python) I don't get any errors until I reach the section *Convert the C++ project to an extension for Python*.

After I go through the steps from this section and attempt to build the solution I stumble on this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CppMain, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>module.cpp
1>   Creating library C:\Users\$andu\Desktop\Cpp4Py\Debug\Cpp4Py.lib and object C:\Users\$andu\Desktop\Cpp4Py\Debug\Cpp4Py.exp
1>module.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyFloat_FromDouble referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl tanh(struct _object *,struct _object *)" (?tanh@@YAPAU_object@@PAU1@0@Z)
1>module.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyFloat_AsDouble referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl tanh(struct _object *,struct _object *)" (?tanh@@YAPAU_object@@PAU1@0@Z)
1>module.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyModule_Create2 referenced in function _PyInit_Cpp4Py
1>C:\Python\Anaconda3\libs\python3.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
1>C:\Users\$andu\Desktop\Cpp4Py\Debug\Cpp4Py.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "CppMain.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

From the message above, I suspect that the problem comes from step 2 in that set of instructions. But I don't really know how to deal with that. Any suggestions?

---

I work with x64 Windows 10.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure. But you can change your project's target machine type to x64 and try again. See this warning:

> C:\Python\Anaconda3\libs\python3.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'

Comment: I should have mentioned I have done that. Unsuccessfully. Have you tried the instructions? Do they work for you?

Comment: Actually, how do you do that? The way a I've done it is by choosing x64 Platform from the Solution Properties.

Comment: OK, I have also changed the Solution Platform to x64 in the Menu Bar and it worked. My problem is now that `pip install .` doesn't work. I am not sure I have created the `setup.py` as I was supposed to do it. There was no Python as prescribes "searching for "Python" and selecting Python file", so I just created a file in that directory and added it to the project.