# C1083 Cannot open include file: "Python.h": No such file or directory

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am following this post: [Creating a C++ extension for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/cpp-and-python)

I have installed VS2017 on my fresh new Windows10LTSB system, with Desktop development with C++ and Python Development (including Python native development tools) workloads, following [Installing Python support in Visual Studio on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/installation)

My Python application worked fine.

I stuck at the *Create the core C++ project* section for almost a day, I created Empty Project following the post and also tried creating a Python Extension Module template.

The error is **E1696 cannot open source file "Python.h"**.

I strictly followed the post to set up the project property and tied several times, but it did not work at all.

My Python directory is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64, which was also my Python application's default environment.

I have not installed the official Python distribution, because [Python environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/python-environments) mentions that VS ignore PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: The compiler needs to know where the location of *Python.h* is. I thought that this would be taken care by the *VStudio* - *Python* integration. But anyway you could go manually. Check my answer to [\[SO\]: Calling Python function with parametrs from C++ project (Visual Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942845/calling-python-function-with-parametrs-from-c-project-visual-studio) the last in the 1st set of **Notes** (the one about "*Build (compile/link)/Run options*") or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156336/how-to-include-openssl-in-visual-studio-expres-2012-windows-7-x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have included my Python directory, which is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64
```

I had done this before, but another problem occured. I found this post [Creating a C++ extension for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289978/creating-a-c-extension-for-python) and retarget the C++ project target platform to x64 in the Solution Property and solved the problem.